# Why does Dropbox's Camera Uploads feature recommend to save HEIC photos as JPG?

Tags: heic

[image]

Wouldn't converting all photos from HEIC to JPG lower the quality of the photos?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1540968/why-does-dropboxs-camera-uploads-feature-recommend-to-save-heic-photos-as-jpg

Answer (score 2):

Because there are a LOT of devices in use everywhere that can't display HEIC format images, and transforming them to JPEG after most of the raw data has been discarded is bad enough, but when the image has been compressed even more by bandwidth saving protocols used by a lot of different distribution systems it produces all kinds of nasty artifacts.